# Python machine learning predict error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a `.csv` file with 26 features columns and 1 column class . I have used

`Python` to train and for test I used 26 features to predict the class  .The code

shows this error :

> > ubuntu@ubuntu:~/python$ python3 classifier.py  train.csv
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:395:
>   DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and will
>
> raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
>   X.reshape(-1, 1) if
>
> your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a
>   single sample.
>
> DeprecationWarning) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "classifier.py", line 44, in 
>       accuracy_score(train_X, predict)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py",
>   line 172, in accuracy_score
>       y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py",
>   line 72, in _check_targets
>       check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
>   line 181, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [778, 1]

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def getFeatures(file_name,length=27):
all_features=[]
all_classes=[]
for line in open(file_name):
    s=line.strip().split(",")
    lst=[]
    if len(s)==length:
        class_=int(s[length-1])
        for i in range(length-1):
            lst.append(float(s[i]))
        all_features.append(lst)
        all_classes.append(class_)

return np.array(all_features),np.array(all_classes)


 if len(sys.argv)>1:
input_train_file=sys.argv[1]       # e.g. input train file
#input_test_file=sys.argv[2]        # e.g. input test file

# make features ready for train set
train_X,train_y=getFeatures(input_train_file)

# make features ready for test set
#test_X,test_y=getFeatures(input_test_file)

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')

# train
clf.fit(train_X, train_y)

#predict
test_X=[0.24    ,0.27031,   0.239808    ,0.271922   ,0.249783   ,0.271922,  0.239808    ,0.271922,  0.261446,   0.27692 ,0.270599   ,0.27031,   0.270599,   0.281724,   0.259792,   0.271922,   0.239808,   0.271922,   0.261212    ,0.271922   ,0.259792   ,0.276243   ,0.261212,  0.27031 ,0.259792   ,0.274605
]

predict=clf.predict(test_X)

accuracy_score(train_X, predict)
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It literally tells you what code to use to fix the problem. If that is not clear, could you say which part of it is causing you a problem?

Comment: The accuracy_score(train_X, predict) is causing the problem , when I print predict the code shows the predicted class , but the score is where the error

Comment: OK right, the warning is for a different line. Do you realise you have used the training set examples and the the test set predictions in `accuracy_score(train_X, predict)`? Even if they were the same number of examples, the result would be nonsense value . . . just change it to `accuracy_score(test_Y, predict)`. You will still get the deprecation warning though (and maybe other errors) unless you also fix that.

Comment: I didn't define  test_Y , the test_X is the data that I want to predict to which class it belongs

Comment: Without `test_Y` then you cannot measure accuracy (if you don't know what the true value is, then you cannot measure how good the predictions are), so just drop that line of code. Your `predict` variable contains the data you want. You really *should* test your model though, otherwise you won't know whether it is any good.

Comment: I have .csv file data which contains the training data (26 cols )and (1,-1) class. for test I have data (26) cols but I don't know the class for it . predict shows the class but I don't know how accurate is that

Comment: It is not *possible* to know how accurate your prediction for a specific piece of new data is, if you don't already know the truth. However, you can get a general idea for it by splitting up your training data into separate train and test sets - in which case you would have `test_X` and `test_y` for the code. See this Q&A on Cross Validated site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set